# ROS Kinetic source installation error - ImportError: No module named terminal_color

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to install ROS kinetic bare bones packages from source. I have a virtual machine running Ubuntu 16.04.

I followed the instructions for installation from source from [this](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source) page.

But I am getting following error after invoking catkin_make_isolated

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated", line 12, in <module>
    from catkin.builder import build_workspace_isolated
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 66, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.terminal_color import ansi, disable_ANSI_colors, fmt, sanitize
ImportError: No module named terminal_color
```

To find the solution to this problem, I looked at the Q&A topic [#294780](https://answers.ros.org/question/294780/ubuntu18-and-ros-melodic-catkin-error-importerror-no-module-named-terminal_color/)

As the answers suggest that the error could be because of mismatch in versions of  python-catkin-pkg and python-catkin-pkg-models

the output of `dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg` in my case is

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/catkin_create_pkg
/usr/bin/catkin_generate_changelog
/usr/bin/catkin_test_changelog
/usr/bin/catkin_tag_changelog
/usr/bin/catkin_find_pkg
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.2.10.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/tool_detection.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/topological_order.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/workspaces.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/python_setup.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/metapackage.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cmake.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/rospack.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_version.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog_generator.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/metapackage.cmake.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/package.xml.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/CMakeLists.txt.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog_generator_vcs.py
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg/README.rst
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/catkin_create_pkg.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/catkin_test_changelog.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/catkin_tag_changelog.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/catkin_generate_changelog.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/catkin_find_pkg.1.gz
```

and the output of `dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg-modules` is

```
dpkg-query: package 'python-catkin-pkg-modules' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

I am not able to install `python-catkin-pkg-modules` with

```
sudo apt install python-catkin-pkg python-catkin-pkg-modules
```

The error message is

```
E: Unable to locate package python-catkin-pkg-modules
```

Please suggest a solution for these errors.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312789/ros-kinetic-source-installation-error---importerror:-no-module-named-terminal_color/) by [Rasika](https://answers.ros.org/users/38891/rasika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2019-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved. I could install the `python-catkin-pkg-modules` today and my source code is currently building
Now I am trying to find why this was not working previously

---

Originally posted by [Rasika](https://answers.ros.org/users/38891/rasika/) with karma: 36 on 2019-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1